# How is this form of the Chernoff bound derived from the other?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Looking over the [Wikipedia page for the Chernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), it's given at the top as
$P \geq 1-\mathrm{e}^{- 2n \left( p - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2}$, where $P$ is the probability that a majority of biased random variables $X_1 \ldots X_n$ are $1$.

A little lower on the page, it gives the formula for finding how many trials to establish the biased side as being $n \geq \frac{1}{(p -1/2)^2} \ln \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}.$

I'm having trouble seeing how the second is derived from the first, as I thought that $\varepsilon = 1-P$, and solving the first inequality for $n$ seems to g ive something like $n \geq -\frac{1}{2(p-\frac{1}{2})^2} \ln \varepsilon$. If somebody could show where the second inequality comes from, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Use $ -\ln \epsilon = \ln \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\frac{1}{2} \ln x = \ln \sqrt{x}$ for positive $x$ and $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Sasha answered the question in comments. This simply follows from the [basic properties of logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities):

$$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{2}\ln \varepsilon &= - \ln (\sqrt{\varepsilon})  \qquad \text{since } a \ln x = \ln (x^a) \text{ for } x > 0;
\\ &= \ln \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \right) \qquad \text{since } - \ln x = \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} \right).
\end{align*}
$$